Threshold such that the inequality holds for sufficiently large n
Question. How to find the smallest $\delta\in(0,1)$ which is a function  on $\sigma_n$ such that
$$8\pi+\frac{32\pi}{\delta_n}+32\pi\cdot\frac{\sigma_n}{\delta_n \sqrt{n}}\leq \exp\Big(\frac{\delta_n^2n}{32\sigma_n^2}\Big)$$
holds, where $\sigma_n$ is a increasing function on $n$ satisfying $\sigma_n\prec\sqrt{n}$ (asymptotically smaller than).  It is fine if it only holds for sufficiently large $n$.
Motivation I encountered this question when I was reading a paper in probability and adapting it to my case. The $\sigma$ is standard deviation. The goal is to find the smallest $\delta_n$ which quantifies how concentrate a random variable is, such that the inequality holds. This inequality comes from a very lengthy proof thus I think it would be better to not include here.
What I tried is very naive analysis, but I found it maybe incorrect because I did not take $\frac{32\pi}{\delta_n}$ into account which contributes growth on lhs. What would be a standard way to deal with such problem? I will include my analysis here first:
The asymptotic behavior of $\frac{32\pi\sigma_n}{\delta_n \sqrt{n}}$ and $\exp\Big(\frac{\delta_n^2 n}{32\sigma_n^2}\Big)$ depends on relation between $\delta_n, \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$.
(1) When $\delta_n\succ \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ then $\frac{32\pi\sigma_n}{\delta_n \sqrt{n}}\downarrow_0 $ and $\exp\Big(\frac{\delta_n^2 n}{32\sigma_n^2}\Big)\uparrow^{+\infty}$, moreover $\frac{32\pi}{\delta_n}\prec \exp\Big(\frac{\delta_n^2 n}{32\sigma_n^2}\Big)$ since $\log(32\pi)\prec \log(\delta_n)+\frac{\delta_n^2n}{32\sigma_n^2}$. Thus inequality holds.
(2) When $\delta_n\prec \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ then $\frac{32\pi\sigma_n}{\delta_n \sqrt{n}}\uparrow^{+\infty}$ and $\exp\Big(\frac{\delta_n^2 n}{32\sigma_n^2}\Big)\downarrow_0 $, then inequality doesn't hold.
(3) When $\delta\sim \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$, then lhs$\rightarrow +\infty$ while rhs is constant, thus the inequality doesn't hold.

What is meant by "$\delta$ is a function on $\sigma$"? Also, if $\sigma$ is a function of $n$ then you can clarify that by writing $\sigma_n$. It would also help to specify what is assumed about $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ (is it zero?)

@Michael It just mean $\delta$ can take as a function on $\sigma$. This is because the inequality involves $\delta,\sigma$ both.

Is $\delta$ a constant or not? Is $\sigma$ a constant or is it $\sigma_n$ (a function of $n$)?

@Michael $\delta$ is not a constant, it can depend on $\sigma_n$. $\sigma_n$ is a function of $n$ (I just re-edited)

@Michael Since $\sigma_n\prec\sqrt{n}$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}=0$.

Then $\frac{n}{\sigma_n^2}\rightarrow\infty$ and for any fixed $\delta>0$ the right-hand-side expression $\exp\left(\frac{\delta^2 n}{32\sigma_n^2}\right)$ grows at least exponentially fast to $\infty$, much faster than the left-hand-side. So for any $\delta>0$ your inequality holds for all sufficiently large $n$.  If you want $\delta$ to change with $n$ you should write $\delta_n$.

@Michael what about the second term on left-hand-side? It also grows, and I am not sure whether it cannot exceed rhs or not. Also, It looks like we could only write $\delta_n\succ\frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$, we cannot find something like $\delta_n\geq \text{something}$.

Again, if you want $\delta$ to change with $n$, you need to clarify that by writing $\delta_n$.

@Michael Thank you, I just revised it to $\delta_n$

Your cases 2 and 3 make sense but case 1 is not correct. Define $\delta_n$ so that $\frac{\sigma_n}{\delta_n\sqrt{n}}=1/n$. Then your case 1 holds and the right-hand-side of your inequality is $\exp(n^2/32)$, but the second term on the left-hand-side is $\frac{32\pi}{\delta_n} = (32\pi)\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\sigma_n}$ which can be made to grow faster than the right-hand-side by shrinking $\sigma_n$ to zero very quickly.

@Michael $\sigma_n$ is increasing function of $n$

You should say something about your motivation for this question. Does it come from the domain of probability for example with $\sigma$ interpreted as a Standard Deviation ?

@JeanMarie yes, i will motivate in re-edit

For $\sigma_n$ increasing, I believe you can modify my example to show case 1 is incorrect: Define $\sigma_n=n^{1/4}$. Define $\delta_n$ so that $\frac{\sigma_n}{\delta_n\sqrt{n}}=v_n$ for some $v_n$ that goes to zero very slowly, such as $(1/v_n)\exp(1/v_n^2)=n^{1/100}$.

Your cases 2 and 3 look good, but your case 1 is incorrect and needs to be refined.
Assumptions: Assume $\sigma_n$ is positive and nondecreasing for $n\geq 1$ and satisfies
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$$
Define $\delta_n$ for $n \geq 1$ by
$$ \delta_n = \frac{h_n\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$$
for some positive values $h_n$ that ensure $\delta_n\in (0,1)$ for all $n\geq 1$.  The values $h_n$ determine how much larger than $\sigma_n/\sqrt{n}$ the $\delta_n$ values are. We show that the desired inequality requires $h_n\rightarrow \infty$. Further it fails if $h_n$ does not grow to infinity fast enough. The exact $h_n$ asymptotic growth that is required is characterized.
Desired inequality: For all sufficiently large $n$ we want
$$8\pi + \frac{32\pi}{\delta_n} + 32\pi\frac{\sigma_n}{\delta_n\sqrt{n}} \leq \exp\left(\frac{n\delta_n^2}{32\sigma_n^2}\right)$$
Claim 1: If there are infinitely many integers $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ such that
$$  \frac{h_n}{32\pi}\exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right) \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n}$$
then your desired inequality fails for infinitely many integers $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. In particular, the desired inequality fails if there is a $c\geq 0$ such that $h_n\leq c$ for infinitely many $n$.
Claim 2: If there is an $a>1$ such that for all sufficiently large $n$ we have
$$  \frac{h_n}{32\pi}\exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right) \geq \frac{a\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n} $$
then your desired inequality holds for all sufficiently large $n$. In particular, for every $\epsilon>0$, the desired inequality holds if $h_n\geq n^{\epsilon}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Proof of Claim 1: By definition of $\delta_n$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{32\pi}{\delta_n} \geq \exp\left(\frac{n\delta_n^2}{32\sigma_n^2}\right) &\iff 32\pi\frac{\sqrt{n}}{h_n\sigma_n} \geq \exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right) \\
&\iff\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n} \geq \frac{h_n}{32\pi}\exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right) \quad \Box
\end{align}
Proof of Claim 2: The assumptions imply $h_n\rightarrow\infty$. By definition of $\delta_n$ we have for all $n\geq 1$:
$$\exp\left(\frac{n\delta_n^2}{32\sigma_n^2}\right) = \exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right)$$
For all sufficiently large $n$ we have:
\begin{align}
&8\pi + \frac{32\pi}{\delta_n} + 32\pi\frac{\sigma_n}{\delta_n\sqrt{n}} \\
&=  8\pi + 32\pi \frac{\sqrt{n}}{h_n\sigma_n} + \frac{32\pi}{h_n}\\
&\leq 8\pi + (1/a) \exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right) + \frac{32\pi}{h_n}
\end{align}
Thus, for sufficiently large $n$, the desired inequality holds whenever
$$ 8\pi + (1/a) \exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right) + \frac{32\pi}{h_n} \leq \exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right)$$
which is true if and only if
$$8\pi + \frac{32\pi}{h_n} \leq (1-\frac{1}{a})\exp\left(\frac{h_n^2}{32}\right)$$
which (since $h_n\rightarrow\infty$) indeed holds for all sufficiently large $n$. $\Box$

Interpretation: Define the function $\phi:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by
$$\boxed{\phi(h)=\frac{h}{32\pi}\exp\left(\frac{h^2}{32}\right) \quad \forall h\in [0,\infty)}$$
This function is increasing in $h$ and satisfies $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(h)\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore, the inverse function $\phi^{-1}:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ exists, is also increasing, and also satisfies $\phi^{-1}(0)=0$ and $\phi^{-1}(x)\rightarrow\infty$. Fix $a>1$. For example, we can choose $a=1.0001$. For sufficiently large $x$ we have
$$\boxed{\sqrt{(32/a)\log(x)}\leq \phi^{-1}(x)\leq \sqrt{32\log(x)}}$$
-The desired inequality fails if there are infinitely many integers $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ such that
$$\delta_n\leq \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}\phi^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n}\right)$$
In particular, it fails if there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that
$$\delta_n\leq \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{(32/a)\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n}\right)}$$
-The desired inequality holds if for all sufficiently large $n$ we have
$$\delta_n\geq \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}\phi^{-1}\left(a\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n}\right)$$
In particular, it holds if for all sufficiently large $n$ we have
$$\delta_n\geq \frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{32\log\left(a\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n}\right)}$$

Taking $a\rightarrow 1$ gives the threshold function
$$ \boxed{\frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{32\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma_n}\right)}}$$
so the inequality holds if we are "just above" and fails if we are "just below," where the details about the constant $a$ make "just above" and "just below" precise.

thank you very much! but it doesn't answer my question.. which is: what is the smallest possible $\delta_n$

In what sense does this not directly answer your question? It gives an exact asymptotic curve for $\delta_n$ in terms of $\frac{\sigma_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ to within a constant $1$ versus $a$ for $a$ arbitrarily close to $1$! A coarse summary is that, for any $\epsilon>0$,  if $\delta_n\leq O(\sigma_n/\sqrt{n})$ then the inequality fails, and if $\delta_n\geq \Omega(n^{\epsilon} \sigma_n/\sqrt{n})$ then the inequality holds. The $h_n$ curvature is giving much more detailed info. The threshold $h_n$ curvature grows slower than $n^{\epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

I could see that the function $h$ tells how much $\delta$ exceeds $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, and it should satisfy $\frac{h}{32\pi}\exp(\frac{h^2}{32})\geq \sqrt{n}/\sigma$ at least for sufficient large $n$. Also, $h=n^\epsilon$ is one choice that satisfies the condition. But I didn't find exact formula for such $h$, which by then we can have explicit tight choice (the smallest possible one) for $h$

I have edited my answer to give an explicit formula in terms of a new function that I call the $\phi(\cdot)$ function. Just like other functions such as the sine or cosine functions, the $\phi$ function can be written as an infinite series $$\phi(h)=\frac{h}{32\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(h^2/32)^n}{n!}\quad\forall h\geq 0$$
